# SQL Server Management Studio - run multiple stored procedures in series

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I would like to test 30 stored procedures against various input to see if any produce errors. The stored procedure share the same parameters. When I run all of them (even just several of them) in SSMS, the execution runs and never completes. It seems that maybe they are running in parallel and bogging down the server. How can I instead execute the stored process in series without manually executing one at a time?

```
DECLARE @spResult int;
DECLARE @paramA int;
DECLARE @paramB int;
DECLARE @paramC int;

set @paramA = 2013
set @paramB = 1;
set @paramC = 10;

exec @spResult = rstoredProc1    @paramA ,@paramB  ,@paramC
exec @spResult = rstoredProc2    @paramA ,@paramB  ,@paramC
exec @spResult = rstoredProc3    @paramA ,@paramB  ,@paramC
exec @spResult = rstoredProc4    @paramA ,@paramB  ,@paramC
exec @spResult = rstoredProc5    @paramA ,@paramB  ,@paramC
...
```

Comment: Add "GO" after every exec line?

Comment: I would have to redeclare my parameters for every line. According to another SO post, "any declarations of Variables, Table Variables, etc do not go across GO statements."

Comment: they should not be executing in parallel. Just put some print statements in between each one to monitor progress, and see which one is taking longer than you expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *many* ways to go about this. Personally, I use an `IF` to keep the iteration going, and `RETURN` if I don't get the success code back. In your case you could do something like :

```
EXEC @spResult = rstoredProc1 @paramA ,@paramB ,@paramC
IF @spResult <> 0
     RETURN
ELSE
     PRINT 'rstoredProc1 executed successfully'

EXEC @spResult = rstoredProc2 @paramA ,@paramB ,@paramC
IF @spResult <> 0
     RETURN
ELSE
     PRINT 'rstoredProc2 executed successfully'
```

Comment: I originally used your code exactly but did not see the print statements. I just realized that they show up in the Messages tab. I've replaced the print statement with SELECT, so the results and messages show on one page. At least one of my stored procedures takes an inordinate amount of time (10 minutes and still running) using your code above. However, when ran in separate query window, it runs in a second or two. Can you think of any reason how this could happen, since they do not execute in parallel?

Comment: There might be many reasons. I suggest you use `sp_who2` to see what is holding it up. Or even better I strongly suggest you download and install `sp_WhoIsActive`